# Convert varchar in different formats to date

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have a table that contains a Date column in varchar format. The date format varies since it's the date format of a computer that used our program. For example, I have the following formats:

1. 10.7.2010
2. 7/11/2010 7:36:55 AM

I've tried using:

```
SELECT        CONVERT(DateTime, Date, 103) AS Expr1
FROM            MyTable
```

But I get an out-of-range datetime value exception for the following line:

```
7/13/2010 3:33:45 PM
```

I need a way to convert those values to a unified format. Time and the output format are not important, as long as it's comparable (when copied to Excel or something. It's to be used externally, so I don't mind not changing the actual values in the DB).
The database is MSSQL 2005.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to read up on MSDN Books Online - topic: [CAST and CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx).

This shows you all the possible, supported date formats, e.g.

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), GETDATE(), 112)
```

will convert today's date into ISO format and you'll get `20110707` as the output.

For maximum compatibility, I would recommend the ISO-8601 date format:

```
YYYYMMDD
```

or

```
YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS
```

Those always work, can always be converted, regardless of your SQL Server's date, regional and language settings...

**Update:**

Converting your existing strings into `DATE` or `DATETIME` depends heavily on your language/regional settings:

```
DECLARE @string1 VARCHAR(25) = '10.7.2010'
DECLARE @string2 VARCHAR(25) = '7/11/2010 7:36:55 AM'
DECLARE @string3 VARCHAR(25) = '7/13/2010 3:33:45 PM'

SET DATEFORMAT MDY

SELECT 
    CAST(@string1 AS DATE),
    CAST(@string2 AS DATETIME),
    CAST(@string2 AS DATETIME)
```

Result here is:

```
2010-10-07  2010-07-11 07:36:55.000   2010-07-13 07:36:55.000
```

Dates are interpreted as 7th of October 2010, 11th of July 2011 and 13th of July 2010

```
SET DATEFORMAT dmy

SELECT 
    CAST(@string1 AS DATE),
    CAST(@string2 AS DATETIME)
```

Result here is:

```
2010-07-10  2010-11-07 07:36:55.000
```

Dates are interpreted as tenth of July 2010 and 7th of November 2011

And **of course**, converting `@string3` to a date with these settings will fail, since it's trying to interpret it as 7th of the 13th month ..... and there is no 13th month.....

Because of such ambiguities, I would recommend to always use the ISO-8601 formats, which are clear, standardized, always work, and it's always **defined** what date is really represented.

**Update #2**:

Of course, you could also use the `ISDATE()` function check if a given string can be interpreted as a valid date:

```
SELECT DateStr, ISDATE(DateStr) FROM dbo.YourTable
```

In the case of `SET DATEFORMAT DMY`, the string value of `'7/13/2010 3:33:45 PM'` will be recognized as invalid:

```
SET DATEFORMAT DMY
SELECT ISDATE('7/13/2010 3:33:45 PM')
```

returns `0` as its value.

Comment: Again the problem is here how do we distinguish that `10.7.2010` is `MM.DD.YYYY` OR `DD.MM.YYYY`.

Comment: I might be missing something: I tried `SELECT        CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), Date, 112) AS Expr1 FROM MyTable` but it causes no change to the values - the various formats remain.

Comment: @Talha Ahmed Khan: that's one of the problems - depending on your language settings, this could be either of the two. That's why I'm saying: use ISO-8601 format, which is independent of your language and regional settings!

Comment: @marc_s: Thanks for your update, but your example also uses `2010-07-11 07:36:55.000` and not `2010-07-13 07:36:55.000`. This is the line that fails to convert in my case.

Comment: @marc_s: I know that, but some of the rows have format DMY and some MDY, I'd like to be able to somehow `SELECT` the entire table with some unified Date column.

Comment: @marc_s: Is there a way to try-catch this? Something like a `SELECT` on the table with `MDY` and in case of a failure try the problematic line with format `DMY`?

Comment: @noich: you can put your statement into a `BEGIN TRY.... END TRY   BEGIN CATCH ..... END CATCH` statement and run it for one date format first, and the other dateformat the second time, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [CAST](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html) and [str_to_date](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)

Answer (score 0):

I don't found any error with converting above values to datetime conversion.
I think you have data with incorrect date format. Please share such data to get more help.
mean while check query to get the date value..

```
Declare @Table Table
(
    DateTimeCol varchar(100)
)
insert into @Table
Select '10.7.2010' UNION ALL
Select '7/11/2010 7:36:55 AM'

Select Convert(varchar,DateTimeCol,101) As Date
From @Table
```

Comment: The last line that I can convert is `13.7.2010`, the following line is `7/13/2010 3:33:45 PM` and on this line I get the exception. Note that the M/D order changes here. Also note that in your example there's 11 and not 13, which might be a day and a month, maybe this is the difference?

Comment: you will definitely get the exception for converting 13.7.2010 because this is not proper datetime format. You will need to set the datetime format as SET datetimeformat dmy